# NSTokenField selection list shows empty space while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield

While using `NSTokenField` something strange is happening,  as shown in the images below :

As I type `A`, selection from popup is shown.

[image: As I type A]

I scrolled it

[image]

Some more scroll, and it went below the visible area.

[image]

This is a behaviour with all the tableviews.  The view behind the rows are visible , but it automatically springs to normal position. But not in this case.

It is fine in **Mail** app, it is working fine.

My implementation is :

1. Created an `NSTokenField`.
2. Set its delegate to AppDelegate.
3. In the implementation file

   ```
    -(NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex{
       return @[@"A",@"B",@"C"];
   }
   ```

Even  the [sample code from apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Tokens/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013108) behaves incorrectly.

*How can I make it auto-spring or restrict by some code?*

Comment: have you tried setting `selectionIndex` to `-1` or a value between 1-3?

Comment: @gaige: how that will make it scroll back to original position? selectionIndex will select the values of the array.

Comment: How are you scrolling it? And in which direction had you scrolled to get each of the images you show?

Comment: both upwards and downwards.... you can create a project and try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in Mail.app is not an actual NSMenu (Apple cheats, shocking!).  Turns out, it's actually a custom NSTextField linked to an NSTableView stuck in a transparent window.

[image: F-Scripting FTW]

It's a fairly old trick to get around the extremely poor version of `scrollWheel:` NSMenu happens to have implemented.  [MTTokenField](https://github.com/smorr/MTTokenField) is a mature alternative to pulling your hair out trying to stick a scroll view in an NSMenu.

Comment: I conformed your Mail.app with **Accessibility Inspector** and also with **RAFT**. I liked the answer, but still NSTokenField problem exists.... raised a radar for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to predicated the substring with the array content.This will list you the exact matching records(this is the plus point). The other is this will avoid you scrolling as well.

You got to change the delegate method in the following way which will fix the issue.

```
-(NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
    NSArray *arrayContents = @[@"A",@"B",@"C"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", substring];
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:[arrayContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please read my question again yaar. CodaFi answer explains well, but he suggested to use MMTokenField, which I can't. I need something that will customize existing NSTokenField with springs.